# Can I overload function on constant of Number type?

Tags: numbers, typescript, overloading

TypeScript allows to overload functions on constants of String type.

```
getElementsByTagName(name: "video"): NodeListOf<HTMLVideoElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: "track"): NodeListOf<HTMLTrackElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: string ): NodeList;
```

But this code cause parser error:

```
getElementsByTagName(name: 1     ): NodeListOf<HTMLVideoElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: 2     ): NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
getElementsByTagName(name: number): NodeList;
```

Is it real to overload function on constant of Number type?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to do this was added quite a while after you asked the question, but who knows; you might still be trying to write that application.

You can perform the following in TypeScript as of 2018. Ryan was probably involved in making it possible... so don't be hard on his answer, which was correct in 2014.

```
function doSomething(n: 1): number[];
function doSomething(n: 2): string[];
function doSomething(n: 3): boolean[];
function doSomething(n: number): (number[] | string[] | boolean[]) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            return [1, 2, 3];
        case 2:
            return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        case 3:
            return [true, false, true];
    }
}

// number[]
const arr1 = doSomething(1);

// string[]
const arr2 = doSomething(2);

// boolean[]
const arr3 = doSomething(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by the TypeScript language.